# Plotly giving error message "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'" - Python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I only came across Plotly yesterday, I'm trying to find a way to produce tables in a nice way, similar to producing charts in Matplotlib.

Initially I tried to use my own data, and kept getting the error message in the title. So I have copy and pasted the exact code from the plotly website and still get this error. Has anyone encountered this before? Does anyone have a solution. I get the feeling this isn't a simple problem with my code.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/2014_usa_states.csv')

trace = go.Table(
    header=dict(values=list(df.columns),
                fill = dict(color='#C2D4FF'),
                align = ['left'] * 5),
    cells=dict(values=[df.Rank, df.State, df.Postal, df.Population],
               fill = dict(color='#F5F8FF'),
               align = ['left'] * 5))

data = [trace]
py.iplot(data, filename = 'pandas_table')
```

This is the code I have used, that results in the following error:

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'`

If anyone has an alternative to plotly, where I could produce nice looking tables that would also be really helpful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends on your environment. If you're using notebooks, [qgrid](https://github.com/quantopian/qgrid) is a really nice tool for working with pandas dataframes but I don't know if it works in other environments.

Regarding the code, it works for me (again in a notebook environment) by changing

```
import plotly.plotly as py
```

for

```
import plotly.offline as py
py.init_notebook_mode(connected=False)
```

I tend to use offline plotly, which is standard in plotly 3.

Comment: Hi mate, changing to `import plotly.offline as py` and then giving the file name a `.html` ending worked for me so thanks a lot for that. I don't use notebooks, just pycharm, but will have a look at qgrid, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a bug. If you are in a hurry and can't wait for a fix you can do this:

Open `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py` and edit the 'cls' variable inside the `dumps` method as such:
`cls = JSONEncoder`

So it looks like this:

```
    if cls is None:
        cls = JSONEncoder
    cls = JSONEncoder
    return cls(
        skipkeys=skipkeys, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii,
        check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,
        separators=separators, encoding=encoding, default=default,
        use_decimal=use_decimal,
        namedtuple_as_object=namedtuple_as_object,
        tuple_as_array=tuple_as_array,
        iterable_as_array=iterable_as_array,
        bigint_as_string=bigint_as_string,
        sort_keys=sort_keys,
        item_sort_key=item_sort_key,
        for_json=for_json,
        ignore_nan=ignore_nan,
        int_as_string_bitcount=int_as_string_bitcount,
        **kw).encode(obj)
```

Basically force it to use the default JSONEncoder instead of the Plotly encoder. Also make sure the change is not disruptive for any other code where you use JSON. It worked for me, but there surely are better solutions.